# how to select 'first' item with interenet explorer 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

lets say we have

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <p>blah</p>
   <p>blah</p>
   <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

is there a way to simulate `$('#mydiv p').first()` in css for internet explorer 7?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the first `p` child?

```
#mydiv p:first-child
```

Comment: Might be worth to mention that this does not work for dynamically inserted elements (at least this is [what quirksmode.org says](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17).

Comment: `:first-child` selects every first child, but I assume there's only going to be one `#mydiv`, anyway.